# Separable ODE - Absolute values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \tan(y)y' = \frac{1}{x}-2x $$

For the equation above, calculators give the answer

$$\ln(\cos(y))=-\ln(x)+x^2+C$$

without absolute values inside the $\ln$. Why is that?

Comment: What is the domain of $y$?

Comment: the answers seems wrong with an extra $x^2$

Comment: You can do that when the IVP has $x_0>0$ and $\cos(y_0)>0$, as the sign is stable in some neighborhood of the initial point.

Comment: Thanks- I deleted the extra $x^2$. The domain of y was not given in the exercise, and I did not insert a domain in the calculator.

Comment: Lutz Lehmann - I did not provide an initial condition... can you elaborate?

Comment: @MatanE. Do you know the integral of $\tan(y)$?

Comment: Should be $\ln|\cos(y)|$, no?

Comment: Yes. You're question is about the absolute value only? I don't have an answer yet. Sorry.

Comment: This is quite common when you get logarithm while solving ODE. Usually the next step is to get rid of log which will lead to $\cos y=e^{f(x)} >0$. Have to be careful with discarding absolute value bars though.

Comment: But won't we ignore solution where $\cos(y)<0$, if we write it this way? I don't understand why the calculators discarded the absolute values